# How to create notification with media controls for API 16 service

Tags: android, service, notifications, android-mediaplayer, android-notifications

I have a service playing music, and I need it do display a notification with "play", "pause" and "stop" buttons. My service code is:

```
public class RadioService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {

MediaPlayer radioPlayer;
String url = "radiourl";
String action;


public RadioService() {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

    Log.e("Service", "Bind");

    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    Log.e("Service", "onStart");
    action = intent.getAction();
    Log.e("ServiceAction", action);




    switch (action) {

        case "play":
        radioPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        radioPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        try {
            radioPlayer.setDataSource(url);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("setDataSource", e.toString());
        }

        radioPlayer.prepareAsync();
        radioPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);

    }



    return START_STICKY;

}

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer radioPlayer) {

    Log.e("Service", "onPrepared");
    radioPlayer.start();


}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {

    Log.e("Service", "onDestroy");


    if(radioPlayer != null && radioPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        radioPlayer.stop();
        radioPlayer.reset();
        radioPlayer.release();
    }


    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

My notification has to be compatible with API 16 and higher. I want notification buttons to send an action to my service, that will execute a proper case in my switch instruction. Is this even possibe? How should my service look like?